# The parameterized query expects parameter xy which was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I'm trying to do an app without adding some details about a car delivery.
I wrote the code in C# and SQL, but when I add the data to `textbox`, `radiobutton`, `labels`, etc. I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The parameterized query '(@a int,@b nvarchar(7),@c int,@d nvarchar(12),@e nvarchar(10),@f' expects the parameter '@f', which was not supplied.'

But I tried by debug to see if they take values and all have values less `@f`
The length of the columns in the database is 50 or 100

```
if (materialRadioButton5.Checked) 
{
    choose = "Excelent"; 
}
else if (materialRadioButton8.Checked) 
{
    choose = "Foarte bună"; 
}
else if (materialRadioButton7.Checked) 
{
    choose = "Bună"; 
}
else if (materialRadioButton6.Checked) 
{  
    choose = "Uzată"; 
}


if (materialRadioButton4.Checked)  
{
     chooser = "Mulţumit"; 
}
else if (materialRadioButton1.Checked)
{
     chooser = "Nemulţumit"; 
}

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(stringcon);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

con.Open();
cmd.Connection = con;

cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.CommandText = "insert into returncar(id_client,fullname_client,id_team,fullname_team,rendition,condition,team_mention,customers_plesed,exp_felt,client_mention) values(@a,@b,@c,@d,@e,@f,@g,@h,@i,@j)";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", Convert.ToInt32(label65.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", label67.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", Convert.ToInt32(label66.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", label68.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e", metroDateTime1.Text);          
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f", choose);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g", firstname_textbox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@h", chooser);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@i", role_dropbox.selectedValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@j", materialSingleLineTextField1.Text);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
cmd2.Connection = con;

cmd2.Parameters.Clear();
cmd2.CommandText = "update rentcar set inchiriat=0 where id=@id";
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Form2.idddloan);

cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.Close();

panel2.Visible = false;
bunifuFlatButton7.Visible = false;
```

How `radiobutton4` and `radiobutton1` works and the others do not?...

```
 public string choose, chooser;
```

Comment: Debug your code to verify you have values for all those paramaters.

Comment: You're passing `choose` as `@f`, not `chooser`. If materialRadioButton1 and 4 aren't checked, `choose` is probably null

Comment: I debug my code and the @f dosn't take values..

@EdPlunkett because i have to strings one choose and chooser..

Comment: Choose is for that 5/8/7/6 button and chooser is for 4/1 button ..

Comment: You aren't using `chooser` for `@f`. You're using `choose`. If `choose` is null, `@f` is null. Is `choose` null? Please show us the declaration of `choose`.

Comment: This would be pretty brutal to debug... if you name your variables properly, it would likely be easier.

Comment: @EdPlunkett yes, choose is null, in debug appear null

Comment: Chooser takes values but choose doesn't. And it's the same syntax..

Comment: Try initializing `choose` to `""`.

Comment: I put materialRadioButton5.Checked == false and it works..

Comment: @EdPlunkett I see why it does not work, when I select the radio button, he chooses one radio button, not two how I need it.

Comment: how can i separate them..? to have two values..

Comment: I separate them with an panel..

Answer (score 1):

If the value is null then the parameter is not added and you'll get the exception you mentioned. In these cases make sure to check for null and instead pass

```
choose ?? Value.DBNull
```